# Multiple swing event listeners

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling

I am trying to understand about the events listeners in swing.

In my application a UI action implemented in a method raises an event and there are multiple events listeners for that particular event.

eg:

```
public Boolean doAction(){
//do something which raises an event and return true if 
//there is no exception
return true;
}
```

Can we assume that the doAction() returns only when all the event listeners process the event? or is there any way we can know if the event raised in the method is processed by all listeners.

One assumption is that the listeners do not create a separate thread to process the event.

Comment: most of Listeners for AWT / Swing are designated waiting for users action from mouse/key event, models listeners are again designated the same way, you have to test Property(Change)Listener or to use (settable, switable, blockable) Swing Action, you can't waiting for end from set of events fired from chained Listeners, its doesn't make me sence, because killing simple desing and complicating simple thing, mo comments is about, just avoids to reinvent the wheel